# Frament transaction with list fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-listfragment

I am trying to implement a navigation drawer. "Fragment1" is a list fragment:

```
public class Fragment1 extends ListFragment {
private List<String> musicList;

public static ListFragment newInstance(Context context) {
    Fragment1 f = new Fragment1();

    return f;
}
```

However i cannot use the fragmenttransaction to replace the fragments in the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AbstractNavDrawerActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if ( savedInstanceState == null ) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new Fragment1()).commit();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onNavItemSelected(int id) {
    switch ((int)id) {
    case 101:
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new Fragment1()).commit();
        break;
    case 102:
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new Fragment2()).commit();
        break;
    }
}
```

}

The replace method has a redline under it and says:

> The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, Fragment1)"

What should i do?

Comment: If you are using sherlock, you need to define your fragment as `SherlockListFragment`.

Comment: Your Fragment1 is of type ListFragment. And compiler is looking for Fragment.

Comment: How can i change it to look for a list fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,     new Fragment1()).commit();
```

IMO you should avoid having such long code with method call after method code, it's messy and hard to understand! Maybe try :

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
Fragment newFragment = new Fragment1();
transaction.add(R.id.content_frame, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Tried the code but it says that the method getActivity is undefined? No other errors

Comment: @GibranGul : Remove `getActivity().` from the code posted above and try again.

Comment: Removing that highlighted getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); and gave this error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction to android.app.FragmentTransaction

Comment: @GibranGul : In that case you're getting your imports mixed up - you need to check them all to make sure you are using android.support.v4 libraries or not.

Comment: These are my imports:
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;

Comment: @GibranGul : If you are using `Sherlock`, you need to define it as `SherlockListFragment`. If you are using the new supportlibrary, you have to import: `android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` and `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;` in your `MainActivity` and `android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;` in your ListFragments